# Using a batch file to generate hash, but how can I save the md5 to a file?

Tags: batch-file, hash, md5

I'm using this code:

```
@echo off
for /r %%f in (*) do (
certutil -hashfile %%f MD5
)
>> output.txt
```

My assumption is that md5 files should be stored in an .md5 file, but I could be wrong about that.  I worked at an archival repository where a file, say, MS332-01-01-001_01.tif was stored with a file that was MS332-01-01-001_01.tif.md5.

Is that not necessary when storing files?  When I perform the above code, what is it doing (where is it sending the string of hash)?  If I can have the hash as a file, like MS332-01-01-001_01.tif.md5, how can I get the above code to generate it, and what do I do with it when I want to verify a bunch of them?

Comment: You want to save each hash of each file with this form : `FileName.Ext.md5` ?? is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes.  Which, I tried using the output pipes, but it didn't save anything anywhere.

Comment: Try `CertUtil -hashfile "%%~f" MD5 > "%%~f.md5"` in the loop...

Comment: I would take a look at this DosTips batch file [Hashsum](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7592)

Comment: @aschipfl, that worked, but when I look at the md5 file, there's nothing in it.

Comment: No, the resulting `.md5` file is nothing but a text file that receives the text output of the `CertUtil` command. Do you really get empty `.md5` files (of size zero)?

Comment: Yes, they are completely empty.  But they're there.  So that's a huge start!

Comment: @aschipfl, it worked.  I think I might've left off quotations or something, but I got it to work.  It printed `MD5 hash of S:\Digitization\Test\MS332-01-01-001_01.tif:  09edf424ff85fed006c811b829581930  CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.`  I'm assuming if I keep that with the file, I can verify the file?

Comment: As far as I know, `CertUtil` cannot directky check a file, so you'd have to write a batch file to recalculate the hash and to compare it with the one in the `.md5` file; luckily there is already such a script; just follow the line that @Squashman provided in a comment...

Comment: Thank you!  Last question, hopefully: With the script that @Squashman provided, does it read both the md5 file AND the .tif file?  If so, is there a way to do that if each instance (say a .tif and an .md5) live in their own folder?  So, 50 folders, each with a .tif and an .md5 file.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try for this batch :

```
@echo off
Set "Folder=%~dp0"
@for /f "delims=" %%f in ('Dir %Folder%*.tif /s /b') do (
    @for /f %%H in ('CertUtil -hashfile "%%f" MD5 ^| find /I /V "%%~nf" ^| find /I /V "CertUtil"') do (
        echo %%H>"%%~f.md5"
    )       
)
Pause & Exit
```

Comment: Nothing happened.

Comment: No files are created ?

Comment: Nowhere where I can see, no.

Comment: In the same folder that you executed the batch file !

Comment: No.  Nothing is there.

Comment: On my side it works very well ! perhaps your *.tif files are zero in size ??

Comment: They are between 38meg and 86meg.  I tried it again, and it's giving me a `The system cannot find the file 'CertUtil.` error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201345/discussion-between-hackoo-and-archivistg).